# Applying a background image with dynamic css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to apply below image as background image but i am not able to do so.

here is my **setbackground.php** code..

```
<?php

    $header_tile_image_url = 'http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg';
?>
var css = 'body {background-color:#fff;background-image:url(<?php echo $header_tile_image_url; ?>)}';

var themeCssNode = document.getElementById('theme_css');
if (themeCssNode) {
    themeCssNode.parentNode.removeChild(themeCssNode);
}
themeCssNode = document.createElement('style');
themeCssNode.type = 'text/css';
themeCssNode.id = 'theme_css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(themeCssNode);
if (themeCssNode.styleSheet) {
    themeCssNode.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    var cssText = document.createTextNode(css);
    themeCssNode.appendChild(cssText);
}
```

The above JavaScript will replace the stylesheet and apply new one. 
The problem is while applying background image.

below is my **html code**..

```
<html>
</head> <title> test program </title> 
<style id="theme_css" type="text/css"> 
    body {background-color:blue;font:13px arial,sans-serif;}
</style>
</head>

</body>

<script src="setbackground.php"> </script>
<h1> This is my test page </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at the request made by the browser to "setbackground.php".
http://jsfiddle.net/bnEnn/1/
Your code seems to work fine.

Comment: Reinder...when we put direct image link then it works fine..thanks for that...  body {background-color:#fff;background-image:url(http://placehold.it/100x100)}  but here the image is dynamic link which i am reading from database and put into php variable and pass same to javascript body {background-color:#fff;background-image:url(<?php echo $header_tile_image_url; ?>)  then it does not apply the background image in fact javascript itself will not execute dont know why...have any idea?

Comment: If you open setbackground.php in a browser window what is returned? Also be aware that you might want to set this to return "text/javascript" as content type.

Comment: yes i already added header header("Content-type: application/x-javascript"); and when i run it in browser i can see the text. everything perfectly fine..

Comment: Any error in your browsers console?

Comment: no there is no error...

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code needs to all be enclosed within the PHP tags.

```
<?php 
    $header_tile_image_url = 'http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg'; 
?>
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(<?php echo $header_tile_image_url; ?>)";
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Banath..no this doesn't work already tried...thank you for answer

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? "The problem is while applying background image" isn't clear to me.

Comment: I have added more details in question..please have look

Comment: You should check to see if the JavaScript is executing at all. If the PHP code is literally what you have, then it would break because: $header_tile_image_url = 'http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg'; should be inside of a php area.

Comment: Banath.. sorry about that i missed to put that php tag..that i have already taken care..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
body
{
 background: url(../Image/bg.jpg) #10a5d3;
}
```

Comment: Pawan CSS not the problem but when i am changing the stylesheet using javascript then it is problem..

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that the image doesn't load when the code is executed? Have you tried to include `header("Content-type: text/javascript")` code in setbackground.php file before output anything?

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/javascript");
   $header_tile_image_url = 'http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg';
?>
var css = 'body {background-color:#fff;background-image:url(<?php echo $header_tile_image_url; ?>)}';
var themeCssNode = document.getElementById('theme_css');
// ....
```

Comment: Your code works for me (and without header("Content...")). Maybe it could be a server config problem?